# Cascading selection box is not working on Google-Chrome (though works fine on Firefox and Explorer)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, cascadingdropdown

**So basically my problem is:** when I tried the webpage on Firefox and Internet explorer, I click on PLASTICS on sector and PLASTIC RAW MATERIALS on subsector and it populates the options on "product selection boxes. But on Google Chrome, when I click on PLASTICS on sector it populates the subsector selection box fine but when I click PLASTIC RAW MATERIALS it does not populate any option on "product" selection box. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me about fixing this on Google Chrome.

Comment: Link works for me on chrome34

Comment: Yeah, on google chrome, when I click plastics option it is fine but when I click on plastic raw materials option is marked with red and it gives the following: <br/>

plastics.txt  GET 200 OK  text/plain jquery.js:8706 Script
/textdata/subsector


plastic   GET 404 NOT FOUND  text/html  jquery.is.87806 Script
/textdata/subsector/product

Comment: It works fine when I click on PLASTICS option, but does it also works when you click on PLASTIC RAW MATERIALS option on subsector selection box on Google-Chrome?

Comment: Ya works fine, Product list box is filled just as on FF.

Comment: It is weird because on Google-Chrome I get this GET 404 NOT FOUND error when clicking "plastic raw materials" and it does not populate options on "product list". It works just fine on Firefox and Internet Explorer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked on Google Chrome but no problem occurs

Steps followed:

1. Clicked Plastics in sector
2. Clicked Plastic Raw material in subsector

Result:-
Items appear in Product section

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will check it on another computer with google chrome.

Comment: You're most welcome. If you want I can share the image with you also. Right now I haven't uploaded the image over here as I thought the information is confidential.